# Edit node js file without restarting server at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

i'm working on a nodeJs 'A.I' and we use socket to communicate with our others app. I'd like to know if there is a way to update nodeJs app without restarting it at all, so our code is updated but our socket never close ?

I saw a few module to watch for change and restart server, but if i use something like that, my socket will be close and i'll have to restart the others app anyway.

Thanks for ur help

Comment: FYI, you can make your other apps so that if the socket drops, they simply try to reconnect multiple times until the reconnect succeeds.  Then, you don't have to restart them and you will be tolerant of an occasional server restart.  This would also then be able to handle an occasional glitch in your internet link too.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for something called `hot reload` (eller `hot replacement`). A few links to explore the problem:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html

https://github.com/jan-swiecki/node-hotload

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-reload

Comment: This is the right answer, but could be improved with more exposition. As it sits, it's nearly a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) 
It restarts your nodejs everytime it detects an edit :)

My Fault completly oversaw your given requirements... And that you already saw modules like Nodemon. But to clarify i never saw such a thing

-Mathew

Comment: Thanks for u'r answer but nodemon restart the server which is exactly what i'm trying to avoid because it close the socket